# cellarray to matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, cell

I want to import some data in an m file. So for I have managed to create a cell array of the data. I want to convert it into a matrix. I used `cell2mat` but I get an error. I'm new to Matlab, so I would like some help. Here is my complete code

```
fid = fopen('vessel-movements.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %s %s %s', 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',')
fclose(fid);
iscell(C)
T = cell2mat(C)
```

The answer I get is:

```
C = 
Columns 1 through 4

[300744x1 double]    [300744x1 double]    [300744x1 double]    [300744x1 double]

Columns 5 through 8

[300744x1 double]    {300744x1 cell}    {300744x1 cell}    {300744x1 cell}

ans =

     1
```

> ??? Error using ==> cell2mat at 46
> All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.
>
> Error in ==> test at 5
> T = cell2mat(C)

My question is how I can do that? The data is in the following link [vessel-movements.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xys8x5du1s7eh4n/vessel-movements.csv?dl=0). It contains numbers, as ids and coordinates, and timestamps.

Comment: 6th col onwards you have string data. How do you plan to store them into a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says:

> All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

Columns 6, 7 and 8 are chars (datestrings). It's not possible to convert them into a Matrix. Leave them in a cell.

You can transform only the numerical data into a matrix: `data = cell2mat(C(:,1:5))`. The three left columns have to be converted with `datenum()` into a numerical time to add it to `data` matrix.

When you've got >=R2013b, you can use as datatype a table like: `data = readtable('vessel-movements.csv');`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I am using Matlab on a lap PC so the installed release is R2011b. Because I need both the numerical values and the times I will also use the datenum() and then I'll add it to the data matrix

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to convert the first five columns of `C`, which are the ones that contain numeric data. You can use [`cell2mat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) as follows:

```
M = cell2mat(C(:,1:5));
```

or equivalently

```
M = [C{:,1:5}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a matrix and a cell array (in MATLAB parlance) is that a matrix holds elements of the same type and size, while a cell array holds elements of different types and sizes.

You read numbers and strings. The numbers *do* have the same type and size (`double`, 1×1) while the strings are different (they're all `char` type, but usually different sizes).

To group your numeric data, you must select only the numeric elements of your cell array:

```
N = horzcat(C{1:5});
```

while  for the strings you should keep the cell array structure:

```
S = horzcat(C{6:8});
```

*Later edit:* Since you admit that you're new to MATLAB, I'm going to make a general recommendation: every time you see a function that you don't know what it does—or behaves unexpectedly from your point of view—mark its name and press F1. The MATLAB documentation is quite comprehensive, and contains also lots of examples depicting the typical uses for that function.